# Negative fillet (bevel inward)

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, bevel, vertex-groups

I would like to make the bevel go inward. to match the shape of the other module. I can't add a negative value to this

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're beveling an edge you can set the *Shape* value to something lower than the default 0.5:

[image: bevel shape]

You can even create custom shapes if you switch *Profile Type* to *Custom* instead of *Superellipse*.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :) The reason I wanted to do it with the modifier is to work non-destructive, is there a way of doing that in this way (edit mode)?

Comment: @Michael The shape can be set for the _Bevel_ tool in _Edit Mode_ (my screenshot) and you have that setting in the modifier as well.

Comment: ...you just have to beware, if you bevel it completely to the borders like in the screenshot (only stopped by clamping to avoid extending it further) then you'll get double vertices there. To get rid of them in _Edit Mode_, select all with _A_, then hit _M_ > _Merge_ > _By Distance_. If you want to merge them procedurally when using a _Bevel_ modifier, there is no merge option like in the _Mirror_ modifier for example. But you can add a _Weld_ modifier after the beveling.